# Get list of objects from jquery get in mvc

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc

What I want is to get the list of objects in the return of the jquery GET:
This is my view:

```
 public List<CarBrandModel> Index()
    {
        //get the list of carbrand
        List<CarBrandModel> modelList = CarBrandModel.FromEntityToModel(service.GetAll());
        return modelList;
    }
```

This is my model:

```
    public class CarBrandModel
    {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

And this is my js:

```
var get = function () {
$.ajax({
    url: '/carbrand/Index',
    accepts: 'application/json',
    dataType: false,
    cache: false,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (data) {

    }
});


};
get();
```

but the result in the data is:
"System.Collections.Generic.List`1[CarsWebProject.Models.CarBrandModel]"
instead the list of json object that I want.
When I use web api I was able to get the list of json objects just with the same code but using the get function of web api. But here i'm using just mvc .net.

What can I fix to get the list of json objects.

There's a library or something to use and to have to lead with every post or get.

Comment: If you want json, then you need to return json - `public JsonResult Index() {  .... return Json(modelList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); }` but there are a few other issues with your code such as `data` will not contain a property named `total` and it should be `dataType: 'json,'

Comment: Yes I edited that, so please edit in order to not confused people

Comment: But there's not a way to return the object, some kind of arquitecture?

Comment: Not clear what you mean by your last comment. You said you wanted to return json (a collection of `CarBrandModel` objects), which is what my first comment shows how to do.

Comment: You're right, only using webapi can the model be returned serialized.
http://encosia.com/asp-net-web-api-vs-asp-net-mvc-apis/

Comment: What are you talking about?  `return Json(modelList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` does serialize your model in MVC!

Answer (score 0):

You have to written the result as Json.

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        //get the list of carbrand
        List<CarBrandModel> modelList = CarBrandModel.FromEntityToModel(service.GetAll());
        return Json(new { Data = modelList}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Stephen Muecke says in mvc the way to return a list of json is:

```
 public JsonResult Index()
 {
    //get the list of carbrand
    List<CarBrandModel> modelList = CarBrandModel.FromEntityToModel(service.GetAll());
    return Json(modelList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
```

On the other hand if you are using web api, the way to return a list of objects is:

```
 public List<CarBrandModel> Get()
 {
    //get the list of carbrand
    List<CarBrandModel> modelList = CarBrandModel.FromEntityToModel(service.GetAll());
    return modelList;
 }
```

So the answer of stephen is correct. My confution was becouse I always use web api, and now just mvc.